# Cannot login to backend - OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to login into my localhosted OctoberCMS app. Everything works as well, except login to backend page. It stills redirect back to login of backend. When I add incorrect username/pass it works as expected (shows popup with message "invalid pass"). If I put correct data, it redirect back to login of backend. CSRF are disabled, link policy is detect and app_url is to http://localhost.

Comment: Can you plz show us your Auth Controleller / routes so we could look?

Comment: Check your cms.backendForceSecure setting, it could cause issues behind some proxies (like CloudFlare) where your browser is accessing it over HTTPS but the server is only dealing with HTTP